# Selenium File Upload iOS or Android using BrowserStack

Tags: android, ios, file, upload, selenium-ide

Is there any possibility to upload a file on mobile browser (Safari on iOS, Chrome on Android)? Conventional methods doesn't seem to work. Maybe there are similar options to BrowserStack where file upload can actually work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hacky file upload solution using base64 and JS, but it works, so hey, I hope you find this useful:

```
public CorePage UploadHack(string fileInputId, string contentType, string fileContent, string fileName, string angularScopeVar)
    {
        UploadFile(_filePath);
        var uploadHack =
            "(function(){" +
                "function convert(base64){" +
                    "var raw = atob(base64);" +
                    "var arr = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(raw.length));" +
                    "for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++){" +
                        "arr[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);" +
                    "}" +
                    "return arr; " +
                "}" +
                $"var file = new Blob([convert('{fileContent}')], {{'type':'{contentType}'}}); " +
                $"file.name = '{fileName}'; " +
                $"angular.element('#{fileInputId}').scope().{angularScopeVar} = file;" +
            "})()";
        Driver.ExecuteJavaScript(uploadHack);
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: UploadFile here is basically UploadElement.SendKeys("path to file") :) Depends on occasion, might be completely unnecessary in your case

Answer (score 0):

BrowserStack uses Appium to drive your Selenium tests on Android and iOS.

As given [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5746), since Appium currently does not support uploads, BrowserStack too wouldn't be able to support File Upload on mobile devices.